# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established msg91 api

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, https, axios

when i request msg91 api through axios,HTTPS package. eg: below is the actual code.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://control.msg91.com/api/v5/flow/',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    authkey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  },
  data: {
    template_id: 'XXXXXXXX',
    mobiles: '919XXXXXXXXX',
    var: 'VALUE 1',
  }
};

axios
  .request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

ssl in installed on my doamin.

while i was hitting the api it give me an error "**Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established**"
but the same is working in my local system.
if you guys know the solution please provide.

nodejs version : 16.14.2
axios version : 0.24.0

thank you.